# django-rocket-engine is failing as GOOGLE_SQL_EXTRA_PATHS is missing

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I have a django project that I am trying to deploy on GAE. However, When I add

```python
from rocket_engine import on_appengine
```

in my settings.py file, my project starts crashing with this error message:

```
$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399,     in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    commands = get_commands()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 107, in get_commands
    apps = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 49, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 128, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in     import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/koray/Dropbox/code/python/taxiweb/wtx/settings.py", line 65, in <module>
    from rocket_engine import on_appengine
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rocket_engine/__init__.py", line 91, in <module>
    setup_appendine_sdk()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/rocket_engine/__init__.py", line 56, in     setup_appendine_sdk
    sys.path.extend(dev_appserver.GOOGLE_SQL_EXTRA_PATHS)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GOOGLE_SQL_EXTRA_PATHS'
```

The change I have made in the settings file is

```python
if on_appengine:
    ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'rocket_engine.db.backends.cloudsql',
            'INSTANCE': 'instance:name',
            'NAME': 'database_name',
        }
    }
else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }
```

I am on a mac, django-rocket-engine is installed via pip. What am I missing here?

Comment: Not a user of django-rocket-engine but from their github page it shows that the project has not been touched for two years now. There's been significant development in GAE and Cloud SQL...